# How to you test a redux dumb component that renders smart components?

Tags: reactjs, redux

A "dumb" React view can be testing by passing it props before rendering it with `enzyme`/`jsdom`. Snapshot testing can then be used to validate the behavior (as in `jest`).

A smart component composed of a 'dumb view' connected with `mapStateToProps`/`mapDispatchToProps` can be tested by:

1. unit testing `mapXxxToProps` to check the logic is right
2. testing the `dumb` view

and optionnaly:

3. render the smart component by wrapping it in a Provider

However, this seems to break whenever a dumb view starts to nest other smart containers ; the rendering of the dumb view is not possible simply with props, since some child components down the chain might need a store.

Is there a way around that ?

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

With enzyme, you can use a [shallow render](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md) to test the dumb component is rendering the expected smart components, without actually rendering them completely.

Component (`Bar` is a smart component):

```
const Foo = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Bar />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Test:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

...

it('should render <Foo /> component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />)
    expect(wrapper.contains(<Bar />)).to.be.true
})
```